# How to create emulator for 800 x 480 resolution tablet in android using ADT bundle

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, adt

I am developing an Android application for tablet having 800 x 480 screen resolution and Android version 4.0.

I want to test this on an emulator but I am not able to create an emulator for tablet having 800 x 480 resolution. I am using ADT bundle for android.

I created an emulator for above resolution but it is showing phone skin, not the tablet skin. In AVD manager, I am not getting any skin option where I can select skin type to phone or tablet.

My question is :

1. How can I create an emulator for 800 x 480 resolution having tablet skin type.
2. What is the best IDE for Android application development?

   i) Eclipse with ADT plugin

   ii) ADT bundle for window

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers:-

1. Go to Android Virtual Devices Manager -> Device Definitions. Double click on 10.1" WXGA Tablet or any other 7" tablet which you want to edit. Enter resolution 800x480 and clone the device. Now user created Sample device definition will be created. Now you can use this definition to create your own avd.
2. Best IDE for android app development is **adt bundle for windows**. It is faster than eclipse with ADT plugin and optimized for android app development as per my own experience.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Virtual Manager > Device Definitions.

You can find many devices...
Select the device as per your preference...

Eg: for 4"WVGA or 3.7" WVGA are having 480x800 resolution.

Comment: But these devices having phone look while I want tablet look for my emulator. :(

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new device by clicking new button in Android Virtual Manager

Answer (score 0):

ii ADT bundle for window (its the all in one)

i His question is how to make a cheap tablet avd (ie 7" tablet 480x800). The problem is if you use 480x800 the AVD treats it like a phone and if you make it 7" the bucket is wrong.

Closest I have is (I have an actual cheap 7" device it confirm this):
800x480 (800 1st to make it tablet)
6" (making it a sw430)
normal, mdpi

Portrait is good. 
Problem is in landscape the soft buttons remain on the side.